# How do I sort lastname by alphabetical order?

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

*This program is only for sorting the firstname alphabetically.*

**My Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char name[10][8], temp[8];
    int i, j, n;

    printf("Enter the value of n \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", name[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(name[i], name[j]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, name[i]);
                strcpy(name[i], name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Input name changes alphabetically\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%s\n", name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**(output of the program)**

**Suppose,Input**

```
Enter the value of 2

  merge

  bubble
```

**output**

```
Input name changes alphabetically 

  bubble

  merge
```

*But I want to write this program to sort the **lastname** alphabetically.*

**suppose,for example**

**Input**

```
Marop hossain

Nihan ahmed
```

**output**

```
Nihan ahmed

Marop hossain
```

**I'm new to programming so i don’t understand. How do I change the code above to get this result.**

Comment: It would be easy if the code you showed was written by you.:)

Answer (score 1):

the code below should work fine

````
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name[10][8], temp[8];
    int i, j, n,L,k;

    printf("Enter the value of n \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fflush(stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        gets(name[i]);

    }

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1 ; i++)
    {    
        k=0;
        while(1)  //searches for the whitespace in the string
        {
            ++k;
            if(name[i][k]==' ') 
            break;

         }

        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {

            L=0;
            while(1)
            {
                ++L;
                if(name[j][L]==' ')
                break;

            }
            if(name[i][k+1]>name[j][L+1]) //compares the char after the whitespace
            {
                strcpy(temp, name[i]);
                strcpy(name[i], name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j], temp);
            }

        }
    }
    printf("Input name changes alphabetically\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        puts(name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
} ```
````